# How to remove cover/surrounding area of button

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, socket, fitting, screwdriver

I want to replace the button encircled red
But i don't know how to remove the cover/surrounding area

Where should i insert my flat screw driver to remove the cover?
[image]

Comment: what makes you think that a removable cover actually exists?

Comment: Have you looked carefully at all the edges to see if there's a little notch? Maybe stop by a home improvement/hardware shop and take a look at the installation instructions, as they'll probably also include removal instructions. Bear in mind, that you'll be removing the entire gold piece, exposing whatever wiring is behind it, not just the black switch itself. You may find that the switch and socket are a one-piece unit that will have to be replaced in its entirety. (I'm not that familiar with UK-style wiring.)